# Vue.js 3 i18n conditional in translation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I'm new to Vue.js 3 i18n and I havent been able to find an answer...

Does i18n support conditional statements inside translation keys?
Im migrating a website from Angular Js and I found conditional statements in the translations.

Here is an example: (Imagine everything with double moustaches for the AngularJs version)

```
  "TIME": {
    "COMPRESSED_FORMAT": "{d ? d + 'd' : ''} {h ? h + 'h' : ''} {m ? m + 'm' : ''} {s ? s + 's' : ''}"
  },
```

I know THIS specific example could be implemented with pluralization, but I have other translations where is not possible...

Is there a way to express conditionals a translation in Vue.js i18n?

Cheers...

Comment: Vue-i18n does not support expressions in the translation strings - only interpolations. So, if you have `"translation_ID": "{my_expression_1} {my_expression_2} {my_expression_3}"` you can then use `this.$t('translation_ID', {my_expression_1: d ? d + 'd' : '', my_expression_2: h ? h + 'h' : '', my_expression_3: m ? m + 'm' : ''})`. I hope you get the point.

Comment: Oh....well... thanks for confirming...